Image File gets wrong when changing into blob
fetchFileApi(src).then((response: AxiosResponse) => {
    try {
        const blob = new Blob([response.data], {
            type: response.headers["content-type"],
        });
        const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        setImageSrc(imageUrl);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

I've checked that it works well with fetching the image data with fetchFileApi.
I guess something goes wrong when getting blob.
What should I do to work this well?


what type of data is response.data - and what is the value of response.headers["content-type"]

string that made by send_file with python

it's a string? that's not right for an image - image should be binary data - or is the string base64 encoded binary?

try [btoa(response.data)] if the "string" is base64 encoded image
